# Given an arbitrary number of vectors, how can I find a vector with the average angle without using trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I have $n$ unit vectors vectors $v_1...v_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, each with respective angles $\theta_1...\theta_n$, which corresponds to $tan(\frac{y}{x})$. I want to find a vector with the average average angle of each of these vectors, $\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n \theta_i$. The catch is that I'd like to do this without using trig functions, and not knowing any of the angles, only the $x$ and $y$ components (similarly I would not want an answer that uses infinite series since they would most likely basically be using trig functions).

All $x$ components of vectors will be positive to avoid some problems with infinities and zeros (implying $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$).

This is trivially easy for $n = 2$, they just need to be added together. For example given $<1,0>$ and $<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}>$ of angles $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$ respectively, I get $<1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}>$ with an angle of $\frac{\pi}{8}$. This can be extended to powers of two as well by just doing half of the vectors at a time.

I cannot figure out how to do this for other numbers of vectors. It seems like it ought to be possible, but I can't figure out a way to do it.

---

The specific operations allowed are those allowed in radicals (+,-,*,/,^) and logarithms. An answer without logarithms would be better, but I would still be interested and hearing them. Complex and imaginary numbers are not allowed.

Alternatively a proof that this is impossible would be a helpful answer if true.

Comment: If it were generally possible you would solve the angle trisection problem.

Comment: @user I considered that, but I'm not sure that's true. Just because it can be done as an operations with radicals does not mean it can be done with a compass and straight edge.

Comment: @user Angle trisection refers to ruler and compass, not algebra. See this [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Triple-angle_formulae). You just need to inverse the function and you'll have an algebraic solution to trisection.

Comment: @Alien The inverse (trigonometric) functions are forbidden and generally they cannot be replaced by polynomials.

Comment: @rtpax Please list all operations which are allowed to be applied to the vectors ( or alternatively all the operations which are not allowed).

Comment: Thought for three vectors. What happens if you average the three pairs, then average the three averages by pairs, and so on? Convergence?

Comment: It;s a trig problem. The answer includes an inverse tan function of a formula in the co-ordinates of the vectors. I can't do trigonometry without using trigonometry.